# wpf .net 4.5 Isvirtualizng when grouping updating list wrongly

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, virtualizingstackpanel

i am binding a lot of images in listview `using following code

lvImages.ItemsSource = lstVisualDuplicateImage;`

following properties used in ListView

here is my complete XAML Binding ang Grouping is performed iam using .net 4.5

```
  <ListView Name="lvImages" Margin="0,2,0,38" 
                   VirtualizingPanel.IsContainerVirtualizable="True"
                   VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
                   VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping="True"
                   VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling" Grid.Row="1"

                  SelectionChanged="ListViewFiles_SelectionChanged"
                  ContextMenuOpening="ListViewFiles_ContextMenuOpening"
                  ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"  ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" Grid.RowSpan="3">
            <ListView.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu>
                    <MenuItem x:Name="menuOpen" Header="Open" Click="menuOpen_Click"  />
                    <MenuItem x:Name="menuOpenFileLocation" Header="Open File Location" Click="menuOpenFileLocation_Click" />
                    <MenuItem x:Name="menuRemove" Header="Remove" Click="menuRemove_Click"  />
                    <MenuItem x:Name="menuOpenProperties" Header="Properties" Click="menuOpenProperties_Click"  />
                </ContextMenu>
            </ListView.ContextMenu>
            <ListView.ItemsPanel>

                <ItemsPanelTemplate >
                    <!--<VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >-->
                    <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                    <!--</VirtualizingStackPanel>-->
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView >

                    <GridView.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="GridViewColumnHeader">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                        </Style>
                    </GridView.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle>
                    <GridViewColumn  Width="160" Header="Group Details" >
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Border CornerRadius="2" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="#B3B4B5">
                                    <StackPanel >
                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                            <CheckBox Margin="0" MinWidth="22"  Name="chkSelRow" IsChecked="{Binding Path=Checked}"   Unchecked="lvFileItem_UnChecked" Checked="lvFileItem_Checked" />

                                            <TextBlock Margin="5,0,0,0" Text="{Binding Path=size}" />
                                        </StackPanel>

                                        <Image Height="120" Width="120">
                                            <Image.Source>
                                                <BitmapImage
                        DecodePixelHeight="120"
                        DecodePixelWidth="120"
                        UriSource="{Binding Path=getUri, Mode=OneWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit }" 
                        CreateOptions="IgnoreColorProfile" 
                        CacheOption="None"  />
                                            </Image.Source>
                                        </Image>
                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                                            <TextBlock  Margin="5,0,0,3" Text="{Binding Path=FileName}" />

                                        </StackPanel>

                                    </StackPanel>
                                </Border>

                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>


            <ListView.GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle>
                    <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ControlTemplate>
                                        <Expander IsExpanded="True" Style="{DynamicResource newExpanderStyle}" >
                                            <Expander.Header>
                                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                    <Button Content="View Gropu"  Style="{StaticResource LinkButton}" Foreground="Blue" Margin="10,5,0,0"     x:Name="btnViewGroup"  ></Button>

                                                    <TextBlock Text=" Group NO " FontSize="12" Foreground="Black" Margin="30,0,0,0"   HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                                                    <TextBlock Text="(" FontSize="14" Margin="0,2,0,0" Foreground="Black"   />
                                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="Black" FontSize="12" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"  />
                                                    <TextBlock Text=")" FontSize="14" Margin="0,2,0,0" Foreground="Black"  />
                                                    <TextBlock Text=" Items in Group" FontSize="12" Foreground="Black" Margin="60,0,0,0"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                                                    <TextBlock Text="(" FontSize="14" Margin="0,2,0,0" Foreground="Black"  />
                                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemCount}" FontSize="12" Foreground="Black" FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"  />
                                                    <TextBlock Text=")" FontSize="14" Margin="0,2,0,0" Foreground="Black" />

                                                </StackPanel>

                                            </Expander.Header>
                                            <ItemsPresenter />
                                        </Expander>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                </GroupStyle>
            </ListView.GroupStyle>
        </ListView>
```

no of item is complete in listview 
Problem is images repeat and change their position in groups not loading correctly and refreshing is there any way to virtualize groups.

Comment: Can you rephrase your problem. It is not clear to me what you are asking.

Comment: in my listview complete images loads taking no time,when i scroll listview listview not refreshing correctly and repeat images after some groups and mixing group images

Comment: Can we see all the XAML associated with your `ListView` (I am curious if you have any templates applied) and how you are creating your grouping.

Comment: ok i am updating my XAML in question

Answer (score 0):

You have changed the `ListView.ItemsPanel` from a `VirtualizingStackPanel` to a `WrapPanel`. Virtualization only works correctly when the panel supports virtualization. In this case, the standard `WrapPanel` does not support virtualization.

Comment: what was the replacement of wrappanel

Comment: Inside the `<ItemsPanelTemplate>` tag where you commented out `VirtualizingStackPanel` and added `WrapPanel`.

Comment: what panel is suitable inthis condition

Comment: @ZohaibFarid In what condition? If the condition is that you need virtualization then you already have the `VirtualizingStackPanel`. If you also need the behavior of a `WrapPanel` then your options are to buy one of the commercial products (I know Telerik makes one) or try to find a free one (a google search turns up a couple). I cannot vouch for the quality of any of them.